# Accordeon opens all buttons at once in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working with Accordeon in reactJS. I have two problems. The first one is that all the buttons open at the same time and I want them to open one at a time. The second problem is that inside the CSS I can't use a flexbox because I have the title inside the component and I don't know how to separate it (I'm starting to study programming).

```
efunction Acordeon({ children }) {
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

    return (
        
        <div className="acordeon imagen"><h2 className="third title">POR QUÉ ELEGIRNOS</h2>
            <div className="acordeon buttons">
                <button className="buttons style" onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>si tienes un cwk</button>
                {visible &&
                    <div className="expand">
                        {children}
                        <ol>
                            <li>Daremos mayor visibilidad a tu coworking</li>
                            <li>Te conocerán las empresas más punteras</li>
                            <li>Te ayudaremos a conseguir nuevos clientes</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                }
                <div className="acordeon">
                    <button className="buttons style" onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>si quieres trabajar en un cwk</button>
                    {visible &&
                    <div className="expand">
                        {children}
                        <ol>
                            <li>Trabajarás de manera más eficiente</li>
                            <li>Aprenderás y compartirás</li>
                            <li>Estarás más motivado</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    }
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </div>    
    )
}


export default Acordeon;
```

Comment: No, because I have to use something as close as possible to the code I published.

Comment: Does that mean you want to use `boolean` only, not the `id`'s? Are you looking for an accordion like this -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/ ?
How many items can be opened at a time? Only one or more than one?